# jQuery return true or false if a div contains a <p> tag

Tags: jquery, html

Let's see:

```
<div><p>this div contains a p tag</p></div>
<div>this one is not</div>
```

How do i assign a variable with a boolean value (true or false) if a div contains a specific tag like p in the above example?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$("div:has(p)").addClass("has-paragraph");
```

will add a class to all divs that contain p children. If the paragraphs aren't direct children, this won't pick them up.

**Note:** doing this:

```
$("div p").addClass("has-paragraph");
```

will add the class to the *paragraph* not the div. You can fix that by doing this:

```
$("div p").parents("div").addClass("has-paragraph");
```

but this will catch multiple div ancestors. You could do this:

```
$("div p").parents("div:first").addClass("has-paragraph");
```

to fix that.

Or more programmatically:

```
$("div").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find("p").length > 0) {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Give your div an ID, then:

```
if($('#myDiv p').length) {
    alert('I have a paragraph');
}
```

Comment: both work it's just that Daniel's is exacty what i was looking for :)

Comment: I just wondering what the difference between this and @Daniels? @Karim gave the first correct answer, but you have accepted the late one. I think it's not fair.

Comment: there's no difference really. Daniel said cletus answer was the most efficient way to do it and i marked this as the correct one :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = ($('div p').size() > 0);
```

**or**

```
var result = ($('div p').length > 0);
```

This will grab any `p` inside any `div`. This is basically what @karim79 has.

Comment: Although this is correct, I think cletus's answer deserves to be marked as the answer, because it uses jQuery's built-in has() selector, which should (in theory) be more efficient

Comment: fair enough :) why not. Kudos for playing fair

Answer (score 1):

This would be my bet :

```
$("div").each(function(){
    if ($(this).children('p').length>0){
        // do stuff, assign boolean if you want
    }
});
```

I assumed you are looking for direct children. If not, use

```
if ($(':has(p)',this).length>0) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you want to store your information, but the following code will gather all div tags which contain a p tag.

```
$("div:has(p)").each( function () {
    # Store what you need here
});
```

If you have a specific div you want to test the following should work based on a "truthy" value.  I'm sure someone can get you exactly a true or false value through some clever means.

```
if ( $("#divId:has(p)") ) {
    # Do what you need here
}
```